# Simplifying the expression $\frac{1}{3} \ln (x+2)^3+\frac{1}{2}\left[\ln x-\ln \left(x^2+3 x+2\right)^2\right]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, absolute-value

> Express as a single logarithm. Simplify.
> $$
> \frac{1}{3} \ln (x+2)^3+\frac{1}{2}\left[\ln x-\ln \left(x^2+3 x+2\right)^2\right]
> $$

So I am posting the question, how I solved it and then how the TA told me to solve it differently because he said you need to root of $x^2$ is $|x|$. However when my professor posted the solutions, my original answer was correct, so I am confused...

My Original Answer:
$$
\frac{1}{3} \ln (x+2)^3+\frac{1}{2}\left[\ln x-\ln \left(x^2+3 x+2\right)^2\right]
\\=\ln \left[(x+2)^3\right]^{1 / 3}+\frac{1}{2} \ln\left(\frac{x}{\left(x^2+3x+2\right)^2}\right)
\\=\ln(x+2)+\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+3 x+2}\right)
\\=\ln \frac{(x+2) \sqrt{x}}{(x+1)(x+2)}=\ln \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1} .
$$

How the TA made me solve it:

$$\frac{1}{3} \ln (x+2)^3+\frac{1}{2}\left[\ln x-\ln \left(x^2+3 x+2\right)^2\right]$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \ln (x+2)^3+\frac{1}{2}\ln \left(\frac{x}{\left(x^2+3 x+2\right)^2}\right) \\
& \ln (x+2)^3+\ln \left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{\left(x^2+3 x+2\right)^2}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
$$\ln \left[(x+2)^3 \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\left|x^2+3 x+2\right|}\right] 
\\\Rightarrow \ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{x}(x+2)^3}{|(x+2)(x+1)|}\right)$$

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: The TA misses a factor of 1/3. The absolute values are arguably redundant as  well.

Comment: I have edited your post this time. Please avoid using pictures and instead, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to display math for future questions.

Comment: @Dstarred Thank you for your great help for the OP ! OP also can see your exact MathJax input  in the question's body .

Comment: The notation is very confusing; when you write $\ln (x)^3$ it's unclear if you mean $\ln(x^3)$ or $(\ln(x))^3$... regarding answers of others, it seems however to be the first one...

Comment: @Surb I think  that, we do not need $\ln (x)^3$ . Because, this is the same with $\ln x^3=3\ln x$ . If you mean, $(\ln x)^3$ ,  it can be written as $\ln^3 x$ or $ \ln ^3(x)$, I think .

Comment: @lonestudent: There are no specific convention. The most important is that there are no ambiguities for anyone, and for me, the notation $\ln(x)^3$ is ambigous.

Comment: @Surb Can I ask, why do not you write $\ln \left(x^3\right)$ instead of $\ln (x)^3$ ? Because, $\ln \left(x^3\right)=\ln x^3=3\ln x $ and $\ln^3(x)=\ln^3x=(\ln x)^3$  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems correct to me .

The second solution contains some mistake and missing points .

The remarkable point here is that, the original domains *may* change when simplifying logarithms . Therefore, when applying logarithm rules, we generally have to be careful with domains .

---

We observe that, the original expression includes $\ln x$ . This forces that, we have $x>0$ . This implies that, $x+2>0$ and $x^2+3x+2>0$ or equivalently, $x+1>0$ or $x+2>0$ .

Therefore, we have :

$$
\begin{align}\frac 13\ln (x+2)^3&=3\cdot \frac 13 \ln (x+2)\\&=\ln (x+2)\end{align}
$$

and $\require{cancel}$

$$
\begin{align}\ln \frac{\cancel{(x+2)}\sqrt{x}}{(x+1)\cancel{(x+2)}}=\ln \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1}\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}\sqrt \frac{x}{(x^2+3x+2)^2}=\frac {\sqrt x}{(x+1)(x+2)}\end{align}
$$

Thus, we do not need to take absolute value here .

---

As a final note, we see that both original and simplified logarithms have exactly the same domains .